# $3^{123} \mod 100$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, contest-math, solution-verification, problem-solving

---

**The Question:**

---

*Evaluate $3^{123}\mod 100$*

---

**My Attempt**

---

So initially I attempted to list the powers of 3 and find a pattern of the last two digits - which, despite much painful inspection did not yield an obvious useful pattern.

So I then attempted to simplify this and use Euler's Generalisation of Fermat's Theorem to solve this:

The theorem states: *$a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$*

So:

$3^{123}\mod 100$

= $3^{41^3}\mod 100$

= $(3^{40} \times 3^1)^3\mod 100$

I think I'm ok up to that point. Now, $\phi(100) = 40$

So am I right in the following?

$(3^{40} \times 3^1)^3\mod 100$ $\cong$ $(1 \times 3^1)^3\mod 100$

= $3^3\mod 100$

= 27.

**Am I correct?**

---

***Thanks!***

---

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I compute $a^b\,\bmod c$ by hand?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228/how-do-i-compute-ab-bmod-c-by-hand)

Comment: No, I am looking how at whether my application of Euler's generalisation of Fermat's Theorem is correct. Checking my solution is the objective of the question, not computing $a^b \mod c$ by hand @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: That thread has dozens if not hundreds of threads with titles like *what are the two last digits of this huge power* linked to it. When no new content is produced to the site, I vote to close as a duplicate.

Comment: You gave up on looking for patterns, but that can be done. Are you interested in the details?

Comment: Why not @CopyPasteIt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct! I believe your logic does hold correctly. As far as I can see this is a correct application of Euler's generalisation of Fermat's Theorem. $\phi(100) = 40$ and thus $3^{40} \cong 1 \mod 100$

If you need further convincing, simply input $3^{123}$ into https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/algebra/large-exponent-calculator.php.

Again, not really needed, but if you needed concrete proof, there it is.

Answer (score 2):

You are indeed correct.  There is, however, one minor improvement.  Using the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function), you can argue that a smaller power of $3$, namely $3^{\lambda(100)}=3^{20}\equiv 1\bmod 100$.  The Carmichael function of divides *half* the Euler totient function when the argument is even and the Euler totient is a multiple of $4$, which is true for $\lambda(100)$; thus $3^{20}$ can replace $3^{40}$ in the argument.

At a more elementary level, you can render $3^4=80+1$ and raise both sides to the fifth power, thus $3^{20}\equiv1\bmod 100$ as the Binomial Theorem for $(80+1)^5$ gives multiples of $100$ plus $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Correct, an alternative solution:

$$
\begin{align}
3^{123}&=\left(3^{2}\right)^{61}\cdot 3\\
&=\left(10-1\right)^{61}\cdot 3\\
&\equiv\left(\binom{61}{1}10^{1}\left(-1\right)^{60}-1\right)\cdot 3 &\mod{100}\\
&\equiv 27 &\mod100
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The OP began by looking for a pattern but stated
that

> ...despite much painful inspection did not yield an obvious useful pattern.

You can use some light theory to actually predict the form and structure of the pattern.

Observe that if $a \in \{0,2,4,6,8\}$ and $b \in  \{1,3,7,9\}$ and

$\quad 3 \times (10 a + b) \equiv 10 \,a' + b' \pmod{100} \text{ with } a',b' \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$

then in fact $a' \in \{0,2,4,6,8\}$ and $b' \in  \{1,3,7,9\}$.

This is our main (theoretical) pattern and

$\quad 3^1 \equiv 03 \pmod{100}$
$\quad 3^2 \equiv 09 \pmod{100}$
$\quad 3^3 \equiv 27 \pmod{100}$
$\quad 3^4 \equiv 81 \pmod{100}$
$\quad\text{-------------------------}$
$\quad 3^5 \equiv 43 \pmod{100}$

It easy to verify that the *units digit* will move

$\quad 3 \mapsto 9 \mapsto 7 \mapsto 1$

inside each of these four cycles.

Considering that $3$ is a [unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_(ring_theory)#Group_of_units), we can argue that one of these $4$-cycles will end on

$$\quad 01 \quad \text{the multiplicative identify}$$

and that no repetition is possible until the identify is reached.

Since the *tens digit* can only cycle over the set $\{0,2,4,6,8\}$, there are at most five of these $4$-cycles that have to be calculated.

Calculating the $2^{nd}$ $4$-cycle:

$\quad 3^5 \equiv 43 \pmod{100}$
$\quad 3^6 \equiv 29 \pmod{100}$
$\quad 3^7 \equiv 87 \pmod{100}$
$\quad 3^8 \equiv 61 \pmod{100}$
$\quad\text{-------------------------}$

Calculating the $3^{rd}$ $4$-cycle:

$\quad 3^9 \equiv 83 \pmod{100}$
$\quad 3^{10} \equiv 49 \pmod{100}$
$\quad 3^{11} \equiv 47 \pmod{100}$
$\quad 3^{12} \equiv 41 \pmod{100}$
$\quad\text{-------------------------}$

Calculating the $4^{th}$ $4$-cycle:

$\quad 3^{13} \equiv 23 \pmod{100}$
$\quad 3^{14} \equiv 69 \pmod{100}$
$\quad 3^{15} \equiv 07 \pmod{100}$
$\quad 3^{16} \equiv 21 \pmod{100}$
$\quad\text{-------------------------}$

At this point we really don't have to calculate the  $5^{th}$ $4$-cycle since we know it has to be the last one.

We can now use the fact that

$\tag 1 3^{20} \equiv 1 \pmod{100}$

and work out the remaining details for the OP's question.